# Problemas con React Native Expo "exp://localhost:19000" no abre automaticamente y al hacerlo de manera automatica no obtengo resultados

Tags: react-native, expo

Soy un primerizo con esto de React Native y decidí usar Expo para trabajar con este, todo iba bien hasta el momento de ingresar al directorio de mi proyecto y ejecutar el comando "npm start", ya que en mi caso y a diferencia de los tutoriales que estaba viendo, sucede que el panel de Metro Bundler no se abre automáticamente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así que intente dos soluciones:

**1.** Al copiar, pegar y buscar de manera manual el link que me aparece en el cmd donde ejecute los comandos, pero me dice que no se han encontrado resultados para mi búsqueda.

Utilice esta dirección: exp://localhost:19000.

Claro que en lugar de usar textualmente "localhost" use la dirección ip.

[image: Al introducir la dirección que me aparece en el cmd obtengo este resultado]

**2.** Luego intente omitir "exp://" y solamente buscar con el localhost (de manera textual y usando la dirección ip), y en ambos casos me muestra lo mismo, tiene nombres de mi proyecto, pero no parece algo importante o que deba de usar desde el navegador.

Utilice esta dirección: localhost:19000

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Oigan, por favor, ¿alguien tiene alguna idea como puedo resolver esto?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Robert He investigado un poco, debido a que pensé que era solo yo a quien le ocurría esto al no saber utilizar bien el sistema MACOS, yendo al grano He investigado y actualmente en las versiones de expo-cli 6.0.0 en adelante la empresa a dejado de dar ambiente web para priorizar ciertos proyectos que surgirán una Mejora para la plataforma asegura la empresa.

Aquí te dejo la ultima versión con ambiente web

npm i expo-cli@5.5.1

Información sobre la decisión tomada
https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206